# How to show a place-mark with specific angle information on Maps app (Apple Maps or Google Maps)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, maps, mapkit

I want to display Gunshot information on the Maps app. A gunshot has 2 main properties:

1. location - point from which the shot was fired
2. direction/angle - relative to Compass North

Using the following code snippet, I can open the Maps app with a specific place-mark.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(gps_lat.doubleValue, gps_long.doubleValue);
MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
[mapItem setName:self.pUnit.unitLabel];
[mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];
```

Is it possible to **add angle/direction information along with the place mark**? Basically the **place-mark should rotate along with the map** so as to clearly depict the direction of the gunshot.

[image: Sample place mark with angle]

Answer (score 0):

- you can achieve rotation of marker using google maps and rotation property of marker.
- though you want obj-c code, my swift code will be helpful to understand you what I meant.
- replace MARKER_IMAGE_NAME with your image

1) setup google map

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: firstPoint.latitude,
                                                          longitude: firstPoint.longitude, zoom: 14)
let navHeight = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)! + 20
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height - navHeight)

let GMapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: frame, camera: camera)
self.view.addSubview(GMapView)
```

2) prepare marker

```
let bearing:Double = 90
var marker = GMSMarker()
marker.icon = UIImage(named: MARKER_IMAGE_NAME)
marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
```

3) apply rotation

```
marker.rotation = bearing
```

4) add marker to google map

```
marker.map = GMapView
```

Comment: I want it to be handled by the Maps app, not as a subview in side my app.